# How to change product price depending on an option

Tags: magento-1.7

I'd like to know if it is possible to create an option who set the price in Magento ? For example, if my option set to 2, then my price will be price+$2, option == 1156 then price == price+1156, so on ..

Comment: are you refering to configurable products?

Comment: No, it's just a product with options.

Comment: can't you just add an attribute that would hold the modifier, then change the price on display given that attribute? you should also hook onto `checkout_cart_product_add_after` to ajust your price once your item has been added to the cart so as the price remains the same all along the checkout.
Why don't you just set different prices? or would there be multiple options for a single product?

Comment: I have multiple options for a single product

Comment: Your question is too broad, please decide on an approach to take and ask again when you have a more substantial query

Comment: Yes it is possible, if you'll give us more details what do you want to achieve. For me – that question's to hold for edit or to close for too broad.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a custom option for a product by logging into the admin and go to:

> Catalog -> Manage Products -> open the product -> click Custom Options
>   (left tab) -> click Add New Option

Here you can set the Custom Option Title, Input Type, Required status, and Sort Order.  Based on the type of Input Type you select you will see several other options to add one of which is Price.  This price will be added to the product price if the user selects to add this option.  Click Save/Save and Continue. You may need to Reindex and clear Magento Caches to see this change show on the front end.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into adding this functionality in the price models for each product type.

- Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price
- Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable_Price
- Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Grouped_Price
- Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Price

These models generate the price of a product. Small side note, didn't try this. Highly experimental...

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to write an observer for `catalog_product_get_final_price`, there you can do something like this:

```
$optionValue = abs($observer->getProduct()->getCustomOption('your_custom_option'));
$product->setFinalPrice($product->getFinalPrice() + $optionValue);
```